# Corda - Transaction Sizing

Tags: corda

We're starting to see issues occurring when sending transactions to counter-parties over the Corda network, but it's very intermittent, so I'm wondering whether it's a transaction size issue.

1. What is the default Corda transaction size?
2. Can the default be changed, or is it set by the network?
3. How can we obtain the size of a serialised transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Default Corda transaction size id 524 Megabyte.
2. Transaction size is set at a network level, it will be set by the network operator. 
   For development use cases, you can use network-bootstrapper to update the transaction size using command line. Run below command.

java -jar network-bootstrapper-4.1.jar  --max-transaction-size new_value_in_bytes

Comment: 3. Will get back on this one.

Comment: is there a way to do 3?